# Is there any option to send "Reminder" mail for account activation?

Tags: magento, email, magento-1.7, email-verification

I need to **send reminder mail** after user create the account.if user does not activate the account in 24hrs i want to send **reminder mail** to customer like(Your account is not active till now).

Is there any default option in magento or any other way to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t have an answear at user level, but i can search this using the code.

It looks like a cron job.
In this case, and according to this link :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job
You can search "crontab" on your code and see what tasks you already have a cron.